# Why is IB changing the object IDs when opening a xib file?

Tags: macos, interface-builder, save

I have the same problem with some xib files in different projects on different macs. IB is changing the Object IDs of some views in my xib file. I need only to double click the xib file from Xcode to open it in IB and then try to close the xib file again *without* changing anything and IB marks the xib file as dirty so that I have to save it again.

This drives me crazy because it will break all my localizations since they are depending on the object IDs (ibtool).

Any ideas or experiences?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in old versions of IB. They fixed it in, IIRC, 3.1.